# Launch a program asynchronously at startup on Windows 7, just once, using only the registry

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, registry

The program I am launching is the windows notepad (for a readme file after a program installation requiring a reboot). I am working in Windows 7 Professional, with administrator rights.

I would like to get the following solution working:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
Name: myregentry
Type: REG_SZ
Data: notepad.exe C:\test2.txt
```

However, RunOnce is synchronous (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This results in the notepad launching on top of a completely black screen ([screenshot @ tinypic](http://tinypic.com/r/aua6p4/5)), with no possibility to do anything but read the text. Startup waits, and resumes only after the notepad window is closed. This is not acceptable for my use (ti would confuse users).

I could get the following solution to work:

1) Create a registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
Name: myregentry
Type: REG_SZ
Data: C:\launchreadme.bat
```

2) Create a self-deleting batch file at C:\launchreadme.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
start notepad.exe C:\test2.txt

REM **** Delete this script ****
DEL "%~f0"
```

This does what I want. However I'd like to know:

**Is there is a cleaner way to do this, without generating this batch file first, so: only using the registry?**

This could be useful to others, as the web is full of example of "how to launch the notepad once from the registry", yet none of them (that I could find) mention this issue.

Additional information:

1. I could not get "start" to work in the registry entry (`start notepad.exe C:\test1.txt` does nothing on startup).
2. RunServicesOnce (instead of RunOnce), which used to launch programs once, asynchronously, apparently doesn't exist anymore in Windows 7.
3. Run (instead of RunOnce) is also asynchronous and works well. But obviously I don't want to launch this readme file after every reboot.

Comment: What about writing it to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` instead? This won't be executed until the user logs in.

Comment: @Ken White: To be fair I had not tested your solution. However, I'm writing in the registry from an (NSIS) installer which requests administrator rights. Due to that HKCU would probably not work if the user doesn't have administrator rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the batch file approach without needing a batch file:

```
cmd /c "start notepad"
```

Comment: For future reference, registry data used "cmd /c "start notepad.exe ^"C:\path with spaces\readme.txt^""